# Getting Promise pending on Firebase cloud functions

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to retreive price node from the firebase database inside cloud functions but when I log `getPrice()` function it is giving me Promise is pending warning. Anything I'm missing here?

```
get price Promise {
  <pending>,
  domain: 
   Domain {
     domain: null,
     _events: { error: [Function] },
     _eventsCount: 1,
     _maxListeners: undefined,
     members: [] } }
```

Here's the code snippet

```
const price = getPrice();
console.log(getPrice());

function getPrice() {
    return db
        .ref(`/locations/${id}/price`)
        .once('value')
        .then(snapshot => {
            console.log('snapshot: ', snapshot.val());
            return snapshot.val();
        });
}
```

edit
Getting this log message when calling .then() on the promise

```
console.log(getPrice().then(data => data))
```

```
get price Promise {
  <pending>,
  domain: 
   Domain {
     domain: null,
     _events: { error: [Function] },
     _eventsCount: 1,
     _maxListeners: undefined,
     members: [] } }
```

Comment: You're missing the fact that getPrice returns a promise rather than the actual data.  But you seem to already know that.  Not sure what else to say here - you can't turn an async function into an async one.

Comment: @DougStevenson but how to get the data? The console.log('snapshot: ', snapshot.val()); is returning the correct value.

Comment: Use the then() method on the promise.

Comment: @DougStevenson still not working. Check the edits

Comment: You're logging a DataSnapshot.  Deal with it as such. https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.DataSnapshot

Comment: @DougStevenson Sorry that log message was for another code. I used .then() on a promise but it is still returning promise pending warning.

Comment: I'm trying to return snapshot.val() from the getPrice function but why is it returning a promise

Answer (score 0):

Using async/await solved the problem
[Video on using async await in cloud functions](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jr7pDZ1RAUg&index=6&list=PLl-K7zZEsYLkPZHe41m4jfAxUi0JjLgSM)

solution:

```
console.log('getDataFromNode', await getDataFromNode());

async function getDataFromNode() {
    const node = await db.ref(`/locations/${parkingId}/price
    const data = await node.once('value');
    return data.val();
}
```